# Get duplicate employee count department wise in single sql

Tags: sql

```
ID       Name        dep_id
1        A           1
2        B           2
3        A           1
4        A           2
5        B           2
6        A           2
```

Comment: Please explain more what you want to achieve and add expected output to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to have such a SQL

```
with tab( ID, Name, dep_id) as
(
 select 1,'A',1 union all
 select 2,'B',2 union all 
 select 3,'A',1 union all
 select 4,'A',2 union all
 select 5,'B',2 union all
 select 6,'A',2 
)
select name, 
       count(dep_id) as dept_count 
  from tab t
 group by name
 having count(name)>1;

NAME  DEPT_COUNT
----  ----------
 A        4
 B        2
```

Due to you last edit( *which you wanted to add to this answer* ), consider grouping also by *dept_id* :

```
with tab( ID, Name, dep_id) as
(
 select 1,'A',1 union all
 select 2,'B',2 union all 
 select 3,'A',1 union all
 select 4,'A',2 union all
 select 5,'B',2 union all
 select 6,'A',2 
)
select name, dept_id, 
       count(dept_id) as dept_count 
  from tab t
 group by name, dept_id
 having count(name)>1;

 NAME   DEPT_ID DEPT_COUNT
 ----   ------  ----------
  A        2         2
  A        1         2
  B        2         2
```

Comment: Why are you answering such a low quality question? Is this the standard you want for questions asked here?